# Transloco - How to avoid adding transloco root module to non transloco apps but incluide the library which needs translations

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, transloco

I'm using the transloco for my Nx project. I have multiple apps and libraries in my Nx project. For one of the project and related libraries, I have added the transloco. But the same libraries are used in the other app where transloco isn't needed. How can I handle the translations for the libraries which are imported into the non transloco app?